# Having trouble running Java program with Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

I'm getting the error `Error: Could not find or load main class ExcelFileEditor` when trying to run my program. I compiled the program with no errors by:

```
javac -cp C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs\*;. C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\src\ExcelFileEditor.java
```

I tried doing:

```
java ExcelFileEditor

java -cp C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs\* ExcelFileEditor
```

but I keep getting the same error. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me fix this problem!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //this allows the Py4J module in Python to use whichever methods it needs from this class
    ExcelFileEditor editor = new ExcelFileEditor(new File(args[0]));
    GatewayServer server = new GatewayServer(editor);
    server.start();
}
```

The package is excel.writer

Comment: Where is  your main function ? In ExcelFileEditor class ? and also could you provide main function prototype

Comment: What package do you declare `ExcelFileEditor` to be in, and where does its class file end up after running `javac`?

Comment: Remove "C:\Users\...\\*" in the -cp arg and enumerate each jar contained in the ...\lib directory; separate each jar with semicolons.  I.e., -cp c:\a\b\c\first.jar;c:\a\b\c\second.jar;c:\a\b\c\third.jar

Comment: You have compiled `HyperlinkWriter`, why are you expecting to run `ExcelFileEditor`? Also, usually `javac` puts the compiled `.class` file in the same directory where the source was, so you need to add `C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\src` to the classpath.

Comment: @DannyDaglas, I can't do that since I'm using POI and there's a lot of jars

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I mixed up the classes by mistake when I wrote this question. HyperlinkWriter is the old class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not specifying where to place the generated class files then its going to be in the same directory as the source file.
Try

> java -classpath C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs\*;C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\Li‌​nkingNames\src excel.writer.ExcelFileEditor

Comment: The classpath still needs `C:\Users\rperera\IdeaProjects\LinkingNames\libs\*` in it as well.

Comment: Use -classpath. I edited the answer so that its more readable.